# Speeding up gather

Tags: c++, optimization, simd, avx2

I have a computation that produces a coefficient vector and returns the dot product of this vector with a data vector taken from a large array. To speed things up, I do this for eight vectors at a time using AVX2 SIMD intrinsics. The problem is that the bulk of the time ends up being consumed by the gather operation getting the data for the dot product.

I tried different ways of implementing the gather, and the intrinsic seems to work best. I would greatly appreciate some advice on speeding this up.

Here is a sketch:

```
__m256 Compute(__m256 input)
{
    __m256 coefficients[56] = ComputeCoefficients(input);

    __m256i indices = ComputeIndices(input);

    __m256 sum = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 56; ++i)
    {
        __m256 data = _mm256_i32gather_ps(bigArray + i, indices, sizeof(float)); // 
        sum = _m256_fmadd_ps(coefficients[i], data, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What are the indices like? Any useful patterns?

Comment: @harold, they are samples from a 3D grid along a ray. They are likely to be all the same, but could come from several adjacent cells (not necessarily adjacent in memory).

Comment: Now that I look at it again, is it really meant to say `bigArray + i`? Because that really makes it a sequential access pattern .. if you turn your head and look at it sideways (which the code could do too). Also if the indices are likely the same, that gives an obvious fast-path where you test for that and then enter a loop that has the gather replaced by a broadcast.

Comment: @harold, I ended up just adding a fast path — it helped.

Comment: @DonReba, How do you generate indices?

Comment: However, if it's possible don't use gathering instructions use some shuffling and permuting instead.

Comment: @FackedDoctor, the indices are 8 spatial locations along a ray converted to 3D grid cell offsets. There are 56 floats per cell and 8 dot products computed in parallel.

Comment: @DonReba, Did not understand the indices computations. Please talk with some codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first make sure that you are using the most recent Intel processor possible. Intel has invested a lot of engineering in improving the gather instruction.

This being said, it is not magical. If there are cache misses, you will pay a price for them.

I would try to write the same code without SIMD instructions. Is it about the same speed? If it is, then chances are good that your are limited by memory access. Vectorization is good to solve *computational* limitations, and to write and store data in vector-size units, but even in principle, it cannot be expected to help much with problems bound by random access and cache issues.

Your code repeatedly calls `VPGATHERDPS`. According to Agner Fog, this instruction has a latency of 12 cycles and a throughput of one instruction every 4 cycles. The latency is, of course, a best-case scenario, cache misses will increase the latency.

You should benchmark your code and ensure that you are close to 4 cycles per loop iteration. The main loop should complete in about 300 cycles, and that's quite fast all things said.

You do not tell us a lot about your problem but we can guess that it is much slower than 300 cycles. If so, then you are probably having cache issues. If your table is large and you are accessing it randomly, then it is a hard problem. If you need better performance, you may need to reengineer the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I might come back to this problem and make more measurements. One of the things I was looking for is whether anyone would suggest manual prefetching. I'm not sure I understand it well enough to use it effectively, and my experiments with it gave intermittent and often surprising results. But, since no one said — oh, yes, you speed up slow gathers with prefetching — I decided not to go farther down that road.

Comment: And thanks for referencing Agner Fog, I'll have to read his blog.